# How do I render only two fields from my model as JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, field, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 5 app and have a Person model with many attributes including

```
id
name
```

I want to render these two attributes from a list of people that I find.  I tried this

```
        format.js {
      render :json => @people.to_json(include: [:id, :name])
    }
```

in which "@people" is an array of Person objects, but the above results in a

```
undefined method `serializable_hash' for 16:Integer
```

error.  What's the proper way to render only two fields from my Person model?

Comment: You should look into something like https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers to alleviate some of the pain that comes with serializing objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `only:`  instead of `include:`

```
format.js {
  render :json => @people.to_json(only: [:id, :name])
}
```

While `only` will give you only the wanted attributes from that model, `include` is meant to include other associations of the models! (associations as `belong_to` or `has_many` etc)

Anyway, there is another way of getting the same result using `select` on the model query.

```
@poeple = Person.select(:id, :name).where(....)
```

and then just return the `to_json` -> you don't need to exclude any attribute since you only get the attributes you want in first place.

** The 2nd method is only good if you don't need other attributes in other cases. For example if you want to return the full list of attributes of the model if its not json